# Import text file from website to powerbi using panda dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerbi

[TEXT OUTPUT EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGkkL.jpg)I need to import csv text files I import using python request. My code can import the data from a website with my own API key. But to get it imported to POwerBI it has to be converted to a dataframe. But I cant workout how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
response = requests.get('https://my url websaite', headers=headers)
wrapper = csv.reader(response.text.strip().split('\n'))
for record in wrapper:
    A = str(record[0])
    B = str(record[1])
    C = str(record[2])
    D = str(record[3])
    E = str(record[4])
    F = str(record[5])
    G = str(record[6])
    H = str(record[7])
    I = str(record[8])
    J = str(record[9])
    K = str(record[10])
    L = str(record[11])
    M = str(record[12])
    N = str(record[13])
    O = str(record[14])
    P = str(record[15])
    Q = str(record[16])
    R = str(record[17])
    S = str(record[18])
    T = str(record[19])
    U = str(record[20])
    V = str(record[21])
    W = str(record[22])



    print (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W)
```

Comment: Can you give a printout of response at list first couple of lines and we can analyze from there. Some observations, csv reader expects to read from a file not a string object and it needs a delimiter defined (usually a comma).

Answer (score 0):

So I understand the input data has the following structure:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
['DEV', 'J', 'BBBB', '2019-08-28']
['5R', 'J', 'EMAIL', '2019-05-21']
```

and you want a script to convert this data in a pandas data frame to be uploaded with Power Bi.
As a first step you have to make this text data csv-readable by converting it to text that just contain lines with the values separated by comma's like:

```
A, B, C, D
DEV, J, BBBB, 2019-08-28
5R, J, EMAIL, 2019-05-21
```

Then as `csv.reader` reads an IO object (similar to a file) rather than just a text string you need to use `io.StringIO` to change the text to an IO object. Once all (non empty) rows are read, it is straightforward to create the data frame, whereby it is assumed that the first row is the header.

script:

```
import io
import csv
import pandas as pd

raw_input_data = '''
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
['DEV', 'J', 'BBBB', '2019-08-28']
['5R', 'J', 'EMAIL', '2019-05-21']'''

# condition the input data to make it a readable csv
raw_input_data = raw_input_data.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace('\'', '')
raw_input_file = io.StringIO(raw_input_data)
csv_reader = csv.reader(raw_input_file, delimiter=',')

# append each non empty row to the list input_rows and convert to a 
# pandas dataframe, assume first row is the header
input_rows = []
for row in csv_reader:
    if row:
        input_rows.append(row)

input_df = pd.DataFrame(input_rows[1:], columns=input_rows[0])
print(input_df.head(10))
input_df
```

*Note I believe you have to add the `input_df` at the end to have it recognized by Power Bi*

In your case I take it that

```
response = requests.get('https://my url websaite', headers=headers)
```

has the same structure as `raw_input_data`.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. The output file printed is grouped together by [ ] , plus I also have some commas in text , which is being shown as , 'Y, Weekly' ,  the rest of data is separated like 'YR' , how do I get this into a dataframe so I can import to PowerBI

Comment: is there also a way to exclude the header row , as I don't need to import that data

Comment: my main issue is that to get this imported to PowerBI , it says it has to be in a DataFrame. I cant find a way to import the string into a Dataframe. There are Columns A to W

Comment: Can you update the question and give me a few rows of response so I can see the structure of the data ...

Comment: I have added a link at the top TEXT OUTPUT EXAMPLE

Comment: By the way I am a bit surprised the ulr does not give a json object as then things would be very easy just do input_data = json.loads(requests.get(url).text) and input_df = pd.DataFrame(input_data[1:], columns=input_data[0])

Comment: Thanks the code works - raw_input_file = io.StringIO(response.text)
csv_reader = csv.reader(raw_input_file, delimiter=',')

Comment: To add a column to the dataframe just do input_df['X'] = [elements], where elements must be a list of n values where n is the size (number of rows) of the data frame. I am afraid I cannot help you with r and really this should asked in another question.

Comment: As you say you can now read the response, I would appreciate if you can click 'Answered' to my answer. Thanks.